# What changes to the RPC return data will appear due to London hard fork?

Tags: rpc, hardforks, london

I recently upgraded my node software (OpenEthereum) to the London hard fork. As part of my testing, I noticed a new field from the `eth_getTransactionReceipt` called `effectiveGasPrice`. Simple enough...

The question is what other new data fields are present as the result of the London hard fork. I searched the web and found no definitive answer.

I will select the answer that best answers (most throughly, including possibly pointers to official docs) this question.